# Add agent and custom-handler to the same Wildfly deployment

Tags: java, wildfly, sentry, javaagents

I'm trying to configure [JMX Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter) as an agent of a Wildfly 10.1.0 box. Everything works fine with default configuration.

Now I need to add [Sentry](https://sentry.io) as a custom-handler which fail the Wildfly start with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load module "io.sentry" for handler "SENTRY"
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration.<init>(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:64)
    ...
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
    at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JmxCollector.<clinit>(JmxCollector.java:38)
    at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JavaAgent.premain(JavaAgent.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/modules/ModuleLoader
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$ModuleFinder.getClassLoader(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:463)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration.<init>(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:62)
    ... 27 more
```

When I add `-Xbootclasspath/p:/opt/jboss/wildfly/jboss-modules.jar` to `JAVA_OPTS` the error changes to:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load module "io.sentry" for handler "SENTRY"
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration.<init>(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:64)
    ...
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
    at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JmxCollector.<clinit>(JmxCollector.java:38)
    at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JavaAgent.premain(JavaAgent.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: io.sentry:main
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:223)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$ModuleFinder.getClassLoader(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:467)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration.<init>(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:62)
    ... 27 more
org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.standalone:main
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:223)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:394)
```

Is there a proper way to configure an agent and a custom-handler in the same Wildfly deployment?

**EDIT 1**:

The current `JAVA_OPTS` is:

```
-server
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MetaspaceSize=256m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
-XX:NewRatio=2
-XX:SurvivorRatio=20
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap
-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit
-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager,io.sentry
-javaagent:/opt/agent/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=1234:/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/jmx-exporter-config.yaml
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
-Xbootclasspath/p:/opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.0.4.Final.jar
-Xbootclasspath/p:/opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/io/sentry/main/sentry-1.7.2.jar
-Xbootclasspath/p:/opt/jboss/wildfly/jboss-modules.jar
```

JVM version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.6.0) (Alpine 8.151.12-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

OS version (container):

```
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.7.0
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.7"
HOME_URL="http://alpinelinux.org"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.alpinelinux.org"
```

Comment: Are you using -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs= to pass the sentry packages ?

Comment: @ehsavoie yes, I've just updated the question with opts, jvm and os info.

Comment: The problem is it looks like the `JmxCollector` creates a static `java.util.logging.Logger` which is accessed before log manager is configured. I'm not sure the best way to make this work in WildFly.

Comment: @JoaoMorais Hi, I'm running in the same problem as you above. Were you able to get the JMX Exporter javaagent working in combination with sentry?